# Would like to run an Excel macro with drag and drop

Tags: vba, excel, drag-and-drop

I have a macro that asks the user to choose an excel file and then outputs two text files based on the data.

I am looking for a way to just drop the excel file onto the macro file and have it process without the need for opening the macro file, a command button, an open file dialog, etc. I would like to drop the file on the other file and just have the two text files output.

I saw something that looked promising using a VBS file, but was unable to get it to work.

Comment: Use VBS.  What didn't work about that??

Comment: The page wasn't very descriptive about what to do. I am not familiar with VBS and need detailed instructions about what to do. I was getting some kind of runtime error while trying to follow their instructions. Just FYI, the website that I was using was:  http://fulldecent.blogspot.com/2012/01/run-excel-macro-on-any-file-using-drag.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the bare bones of what you need to do:

```
Wscript.echo "Begin..."           'just letting you know it's working
Set objArgs = Wscript.Arguments   'capture arguments; arg 0 is the name of the dropped file
Wscript.echo "The file name you dropped is:" & objArgs(0)

'DO STUFF TO THE FILE HERE

Wscript.echo "...Finished"        'all done
```

1. Save this to a file with a "vbs" extension.
2. Drag and drop a file onto it.
3. If your Windows file associations are properly setup,
       you'll see this output a message for each of the `wscript.echo`
       lines.

Comment: Do I just copy the macro VBA code into the DO STUFF TO THE FILE HERE spot? Or does it need to be changed for VBS?

Comment: I am going to assume something needs to be changed because when I did this, it errored out on the first line of VBA which was a DIM. I tried it without using the beginning and ending SUB statements.

Comment: You asked for the VBS, so that's what I gave you.  Yes, you will probably need to tweak your VBA as well.  You can write the entire VBA macro in the VBS script if you assign a handle to the workbook.  Or you can just execute a macro.  But you've provided nothing other than a description of what you want, so I don't know how else I could help you.

Comment: I got this to work by passing using the VBscript to just open the excel file and pass the file name in. I am curious, though, is it possible to drop multiple files onto a VBS file and save them to separate variables? Say I wanted to drop 2 files onto the VBS file name ABC.txt and XYZ.txt and wanted to read the path names into two different variable ABCPath and XYZPath.

Comment: Just in case anyone comes and sees my previous comment, I figured out how to do the multiple file thing. Basically all the file names become arguments. Unfortunately, you have no way to determine which file is which argument initially, so I used a  `For i = 0 to objArgs.Count - 1` loop to cycle through them and assign them to variables based on string format.